# WCF Service (NetTcpBinding) not working properly in Load Balancing environment

Tags: c#, wcf

I have facing error WCF windows application run in load balancing environment.

---

### Login Error

### Could not connect to net.tcp://192.168.1.63:7000/FFSecuritySVC. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0609450. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.63:7000.

### OK

I have using "nettcpbinding" method for binding and code as below.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CommonBehavior"/>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CommonBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="65536000" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="9000000" transferMode="Buffered"  listenBacklog="500" maxBufferPoolSize="9000000"  maxBufferSize="9000000"  maxConnections="500"
                     closeTimeout="02:02:00" openTimeout="02:02:00" receiveTimeout="02:02:00" sendTimeout="02:02:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"  maxStringContentLength="9000000"  maxArrayLength="9000000"  maxBytesPerRead="9000000" maxNameTableCharCount="9000000" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="02:02:00"
           enabled="false" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Please give me solution for solved that problem.........

Comment: Where do you host your service? What happens if you try to browse the metadata on net.tcp://192.168.1.63:7000/FFSecuritySVC?wsdl (enable mex TCP point)

Comment: My service is host 192.168.1.63 server... client comes on another LAN thought load balancing server. That server is another one.

Comment: I mean: is it self-hosted, or it is IIS-hosted, or it is Windows-servise -hosted. And what is with your mex point? Does it works?

Comment: This is Windows-servise-hosted.